# header files and multiple c programs

Tags: c

I am trying to use two .c files together.  I am lost at how to do this, I have a simple setup for each file but I get a undefined reference to format_lines error when I try to compile.  Any help would be muchly appreciated;

formatter.h

```
#ifndef _FORMATTER_H_
#define _FORMATTER_H_

#include <stdio.h>

char **format_file(FILE *);
char **format_lines(char **, int);
void test();


#endif
```

formatter.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "formatter.h"


char **format_file(FILE *infile) {
    return NULL;
}


char **format_lines(char **lines, int num_lines) {
     char **result = NULL;

#ifdef DEBUG
    result = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    result[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
    if (result[0] == NULL) {
        return NULL;
     }
    strncpy(result[0], "(machine-like voice) EXTERMINATE THEM!", 79);

    result[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    if (result[1] == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    result[1][0] = '\0';
 #endif
 }
 void test(){
      print("here");
 }
```

and sengfmt.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "formatter.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 test();

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("%s does nothing right now.\n", argv[0]);
#endif
    exit(0);
}
```

When I try to compile, I just type this.

```
    $ gcc sengfmt3.c
/tmp/cc7Ttgne.o: In function `main':
sengfmt3.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `test'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: show us the compile command(s) and the error

Comment: How do you compile? Also note, that ‘_’, followed by an uppercase letter, is reserved. Use `#define FORMATTER_H_`.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: When posting a question about build errors, please always include the actual (in complete and unedited form) in the question. Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Another tip about asking questions: Don't edit your question to add a comment. Regarding that comment, how did you get the build error you mention in the first place? Just repeat the process to get the error, and copy-paste it into your question.

Comment: no u dont have to use a makefile. We dont know what platform you are on or what compiler you are using; the 'how to compile' question has different answers depending on what computer you are using

Comment: you said "but I get a undefined reference to format_lines error when I try to compile.". Do it again and show us what you did and what the exact message was - cut and paste it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your main used to try to call format_lines

You need to do this

```
gcc formatter.c sendgfmt.c -o myprog
```

You must list all the c files that you want compiled together

Answer (score 0):

If you have code in multiple source files, then you need to build with all the source files.

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Compile and link all source files using using one command:

   ```
   $ gcc sengfmt3.c someOtherSourceFile.c someThirdSourceFile.c
   ```
2. First make object files of all source files, and then link the object files together. This is more work, but if you have a makefile or other build-system it will be better since only the modified source files will be recompiled, and might save you some build-time:

   ```
   $ gcc -c sengfmt3.c
   $ gcc -c someOtherSourceFile.c
   $ gcc -c someThirdSourceFile.c
   $ gcc sengfmt.o someOtherSourceFile.o someThirdSorceFile.o
   ```

   Note the command-line option `-c` for the compilation, this tells GCC to generate object files. Also note that for the linking command (the last one) the file extensions have changed from `.c` to `.o`.

   The command in point 1 does this internally, using temporary files which are removed when done.

Comment: If I make a makefile would this accomplish this same goal?

Comment: @user3777576 If you only have a couple of small source files, you might as well build them manually as in my first point. If you get more that a couple of source files, then having e.g. a makefile will probably help you. What you do in a makefile should be what I do in point 2, each source file is compiled separately to an object file, and then in a separate step linked together to form the final executable program.